# OpenLayers: Can I drag a feature between two maps?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, layers

Is it possible to drag the features between two different maps?

Now, I create feature on event mouseenter but I would like to insert the feature and at the same time start to drag this feature.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question, but I'm afraid it's a non-trivial job. I have some thoughts but not sure if it's the right way to go. So probably you need to use browser's drag-and-drop feature (if it is supported). Create a custom openlayers control that you can drag and drop features between multiple map instances. When starting drag a feature from one map, get necessary information about that feature (if I understand it correctly, only geometry and feature style matters, but it's also possible you want to change the style) and store it somewhere. And when dropping at another map, you need to recalculate new geometry coordinates from the dropping position and the saved old geometry, and then create feature with that new geometry and saved style.

This is an html5 drag and drop [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp). If you are using some javascript library, check out if it provides drag-and-drop methods.

Comment: But can I create a feature and immediately start to drag it (force OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature to do onStart or onDrag) without releasing and re-capture this feature?

Comment: It's possible, at least you can activate the DragFeature control when you finish drawing the feature. Make the layer listen on 'featureadded' event, and activate the DragFeature in this event handler function.